# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void format(String) from the type Date

Tags: apex, xml, code

The below code is throwing error

```
   Line 2931: Xmlstreamwriter.writeCharacters((Account.Date_From__c==null)?'':Account.Date_From__c.format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a'));
```

> Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
>   format(String) from the type Date at line 2,931 column 115

I tried Changing it to `Account.Date_From__c.format('EEEE')`, but didn't work

Answer (score 7):

`Date` does not have a `format()` method accepting a string. That method is available only on `DateTime`. You can create a `DateTime` from a `Date` and simply use a format string that does not include time-based components:

```
DateTime.newInstance(myDate.year(), myDate.month(), myDate.day()).format('MY_FORMAT_STRING');
```

There's a number of Ideas out there you can vote on, although the point totals suggest they'll never be looked at: [one](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000lBfxAAE) and [two](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003ZldQAE) (mine).